# How do I produce Spellable hash or Pronounceable hash?

Tags: python, hash, cryptography

Suppose I want hash this `Hello World!`

I expect the output is random word (no meaning) but it's easy (maybe only for me) to speak or pronounce or spell like this:
`acolamesaba` or maybe `olapitozida`

the length of output in this case is 11 characters.

We know vowel = (a,i,u,e,o)
and consonant = (other than vowel)

So how output pattern is: vowel+consonant+vowel+consonant+vowel+consonant+...+vowel

Maybe modified common hash algorithm like sha256 and md5 can help.

Just an example from my perspective definition what is unspellable hash: `cdhrswyxcew`, so it's basically other than my output pattern rule.

Comment: Chose 16 vowel-consonant pairs: ar, ag, el, es, in, ip, ...  Take the hex version of the hash and replace each hex digit with the equivalent letter pair from your list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
with modified sha256

```
from hashlib import sha256

def spellableHash(inp):
  vowel = ['a','i','u','e','o']
  consonant = ['b','c','d','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','r','s','t','v','w','y']
  lenCons = len(consonant)
  lenVow = len(vowel)

  hashed = sha256(inp.encode())
  digested = hashed.digest()[:11]

  result=""
  for i,v in enumerate(digested):
    if i%2 == 0:
      result+=vowel[v%lenVow]
    else:
      result+=consonant[v%lenCons]
  return result

print(spellableHash("Hello World!")) #usuyuguware
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an algorithm specifically for this purpose, called the [Bubble Babble Binary Data Encoding](https://web.mit.edu/kenta/www/one/bubblebabble/spec/jrtrjwzi/draft-huima-01.txt).  You take a normal cryptographic hash, like SHA-256, and then encode it using the Bubble Babble algorithm.

It alternates between vowels and consonants and contains a small amount of redundancy to detect errors.